# How can I frequently change the image in a Tkinter button or label without memory leakage in a tk.Tk multi-frame app?

Tags: python, image, button, memory-leaks, tkinter

I building an app which frequently places images on buttons to provide internationalised indicators of aspects of status. I would prefer that the widget is a button: allowing the user to click and open an appropriate page for further information.

My app requires that the status indication is shown on all pages which are built together using the tk.Tk multi-frame container method. My code worked but it suffered a serious memory leakage.

My studies of this problem has given me the understanding that the `.config(image=abc)` mapping method can be memory efficient (with no memory leakage) if all of the references are "within the scope of the local function".

I have tried to illustrate the structural difficulties that I am facing with the attached cut-down code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from datetime import *
from time import strftime

time2=datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
baton_chge=True

class Stat_Ind(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Button.__init__(self)
        no_faults_ind_1 = tk.PhotoImage(file='green_warning_1.gif')
        self.text=""
        self.command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageThree)
        self.config(image=no_faults_ind_1)
        self.width="40"
        self.height="40"
        self.img = no_faults_ind_1  #store a reference to the image!
        self.place(x=749, y=5)
    def show_image_1(self):
        img_1 = tk.PhotoImage(file='red_warning.gif')
        self.config(image=img_1)
        self.img = img_1  #store a reference to the image!
    def show_image_2(self):
        img_2 = tk.PhotoImage(file='green_warning_1.gif')
        self.config(image=img_2)
        self.img = img_2  # store a reference to the image!

def second_tick(): #This is an infinite looping using .after delay
    global time1, time2, time3, baton_chge
    time3=datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if time3 != time2:
        time1.set('Time: ' + time3)
        if baton_chge==True:           #1st second 
            Stat_Ind.show_image_1
            print('Showing red warning image!')
            baton_chge=False
        elif baton_chge==False:        #2nd second    
            Stat_Ind.show_image_2
            print('Showing green warning image!')
            baton_chge=True
        time2=time3
    app.after(200, second_tick)# calls itself 5 x per sec: smooth operation!

class Changing_Inds(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        #Initialising Tkinter    

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, 'Changing Indicator Images')
        tk.Tk.geometry(self, '800x480')#This is the size of the screen!
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(fill='both', expand= True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure (0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (PageOne,                 
                  PageTwo,                   
                  PageThree):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            frame.configure(background= 'ivory2'),
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def show_frame(self, cont):       
        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller=controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        global time1, time2
        time1 = tk.StringVar()

        indicators=Stat_Ind(self, controller.tk)

        timelabel=tk.Label(self, textvariable=time1,
                         background= 'ivory2', foreground= 'black')
        timelabel.place(x=200, y=10)

        gotopage2=tk.Button(self, text= 'Page\nTwo',        
                              command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo),
                              height=2, width=12)
        gotopage2.place(x=20, y=80)

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        timelabel=tk.Label(self, textvariable=time1,
                         background= 'ivory2', foreground= 'black')
        timelabel.place(x=200, y=10)

        gotopage3=tk.Button(self, text= 'Page\nThree',
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame  (PageThree),                                 
                            height=2, width=12)
        gotopage3.place(x=20, y=180)

class PageThree(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        timelabel=tk.Label(self, textvariable=time1,
                         background= 'ivory2', foreground= 'black')
        timelabel.place(x=200, y=10)


        gotopage1=tk.Button(self, text= 'Page\nOne',
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne),
                               height=2, width=12)
        gotopage1.place(x=20, y=380)


app = Changing_Inds()             
app.after(1000, second_tick)
app.mainloop()
```

As you can see I have not managed to "keep all references within the scope of the local function" but my structure emulates the calling format (to class methods) that would be most convenient.

I think that the textbook examples often use a contrived solution (eg using the random module to select images within a button handler method). I need to pass my "image calls" from outside in the manner that I have tried to explain in the code snippet.

How can I re-structure this code so that it can work (without memory leakage)?
What do I have to do to make the lambda function handler work?

On further reflection I feel that I may have asked an unreasonable question. The button widget is designed as a sort of "command" button that causes a piece of code to run if clicked. I presume that the image that it can be configured to show was really feature that was really supposed to be present when the button is constructed and can only be changed by the events that the button is designed to recognise such as when it is clicked. Perhaps comments on this understanding is a better use of this web-site?